# Why doesn't Android recognize my SD card when my computer does?

Tags: sd-card

There appears to be a problem with my micro SD card. It is 8 GB (really 7.4) is not recognized/mountable by my phone. When I put it into an SD card adapter, I can see everything on the card perfectly. Note this this is the original card provided by Samsung when I bought the phone.

However, I have a 2 GB SD card from PNY and it works without issue.

What does this mean? Why can one card be read while the other (which has been working for about a year now) cannot?

<sup><sub>The old post can be found in the [edit revisions](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/56630/4).</sub></sup>

Comment: Is there an item in *Settings→Storage* to format/delete the card? Then this would be the first choice. Alternatively, you could use a card reader, and do the formatting with your PC.

Comment: That leaves the "external solution" via card reader. Take care not to format it with NTFS; usually cards ship with a FAT file system.

Comment: That *might* be possible, but depends on how the card is offered to the computer. If it's still using [UMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Mass_Storage), that should work. But with newer devices (Android 3.x and up) many devices switched to [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol); with that it doesn't work as it includes no direct (low-level) access.

Comment: 1) I didn't say that – but it might, yes. 2) Even if it does, I don't think it's worth the trouble; it's much easier to simply use a cardreader, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: As you wish. But card readers come for 10 bucks or less, not that big investment. Before downgrading, you might want to check first whether the card is already offered in UMS mode. Moreover, I'm not sure whether Android will offer the drive at all if it cannot deal with the card itself (in which case your work would be in vain). A card reader always does (except when the card is really unusuable, hardware-wise).

Comment: I've summed up everything from the comments, and included a few additional details. Just being curious: which approach lead to your success?

Comment: That really sounds like the card is "gone for good" and can be trusted no longer. Save its data, and get yourself a new one. Make sure not to take a "cheap class-2"; class-4 is OK, class-6 recommended, class-10 a bit pricey but cannot hurt if you prefer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to this. Not all of them are available on all devices, so you might have to "skip" some. I will list them in the "order of their convenience", i.e. easy and non-destructive things first:

- Check *Settings→Storage* for some entry to delete/format the card
- Connect your device to your computer via USB. If you're lucky, the card will be offered to it in [UMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Mass_Storage) mode. Then use your computer's tool to format the card (take care to not use NTFS as file system, Android can't handle it. To be on the safe side, cards usually ship with FAT file systems)
- Remove the card from your device, and use a card-reader to attach it to your computer. Format it using your computer's tool, as described in the previous example.
- As many manufacturers decided to replace [UMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Mass_Storage) with [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol), if none of the above works for you a downgrade to an Android version before 3.x might bring back UMS support. But that should be left as the very last ressort; after all, a card reader comes cheap. Depending on the device, there might even be possibilities to enable UMS using a hack or a specific app (provided the device is rooted), see e.g. [Enable USB Mass Storage mode in LG Optimus 4X HD](http://tutznet.com/3416-enable-usb-mass-storage-mode-in-lg-optimus-l7/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use sdisk. Sdisk is a scriptable fdisk. Or you can use fdisk. Here is an example for a sdisk script:

```
    sdisk /dev/sdcard/ << EOF
    0,400
    EOF
```

Comment: Do you have the complete command for this? just type `sdisk` on adb?

Comment: Oh... You might want to edit the sdisk in your example. :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Insert it on a card reader and connect it to a pc.

2.Back up your files by making copies of them.

3.Insert it on your phone again.

4. since you already have a back up on your pc just reformat it according to your phone's liking. It should be readable again with  no memory.
5. Insert Sd in the card reader again then just copy your backed up files (copy so you can have a back up on your computer as well, better yet try accessing free cloud storages to again back up your files, they're rampant just choose).